# Volume of the solid whose base is the region enclosed by y=x^2 and y=1 with square cross sections

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

I am trying to calculate the volume between $y=x^2$ and $y=1$ that has square cross-sections. It would look like a hump with curved sides and square edges.

This is the integral I thought would calculate the volume:

$$\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^2dx = \frac{16}{15} \approx 1.066667$$

But I think that it is wrong. Is that answer correct?

Comment: $1-x^2$ represents the side of square cross section and your integral looks good to me. Any particular reason you think it is wrong ? :)

Comment: @ganeshie8 - The website where I submit my HW says that it is wrong. I'm starting to think the its the website that is wrong.

Comment: could you try entering the answer $2$ and see if it says correct ?

Comment: 2 was correct. But why?

Comment: $2$ is the answer if we assume the cross sections were perpendicular to $y$ axis : $$\int\limits_0^1 \left(\sqrt{y} - (- \sqrt{y})\right)^2 dy$$

Comment: Put that as an answer and I'll accept it. It did say perpendicular to the Y axis, but I didn't know exactly what that meant. Thanks.